# Flutter plugin mot installed still occurs even if I have installed it

Tags: flutter

[image]

I am working on Windows so the following command does not work.

```
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last command you mentioned is specifically for MAC users not for Windows. 
Anyhow, try the below commands and check if it is working fine.

```
flutter channel dev
flutter upgrade
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
flutter doctor -v
```

Note: Make sure to change commands based on your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue with the following ways.

Requirement: You have Git installed on your machine.

1. Create a folder, for example, `src` directly in a root path. This procedure is the same as what explained in the flutter official download page. So you now have `d:\src` for example.
2. Open powershell or cmd, navigate to `d:\src` and execute `git clone -b master https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git`. You need to select `master` branch here because the `stable` version still has your issue (as of the time of writing).
3. Once the cloning finishes, execute `flutter doctor -v`. The problem should vanish.
4. You might need to set write access  to the `flutter` folder such that Android Studio can create Flutter project files, etc.